# Magento2 add new Column on Cart Page and store in quote_items table

Tags: magento2

I added a new Column on Cart Page
Using this link : https://magecomp.com/blog/add-extra-new-column-on-shopping-cart-page-magento-2/
and add new field in quote_items table.

How to add this new Column on quote_items table on UpdatecartItems?

Please Check : [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Create an Module to add new input column on Cart Page at update cart that column value store in quote_items table and on Place Order automatically store in sales_order_items table.

You can fetch this Fields anywhere.

I Fetch this field in Order Summary at checkout page.

https://github.com/Naeem-Dhattiwala/NewFieldCartPage.git

Answer (score 0):

using plugin
**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
        <plugin name="interceptUpdateProductToCart" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\updateCart"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**updateCart.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;


class updateCart
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    protected $quote;

    /**
     * Plugin constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
    ) {
        $this->quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $subject
     * @param $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeupdateItems(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $subject,$data)
    {
        $quote = $subject->getQuote();
        $quote->setData('custom_column', $customData); // Fill your custom data

        return [$data];

    }
}
```